# Getting Rendering Parameter Values from inside a Custom Submit Action

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am trying to get the Rendering Parameters from my form, inside a Custom Submit Action I have created.

`var parameters = RenderingContext.CurrentOrNull;` is always returning null.

How can I get to the Rendering Parameters defined for my form, from inside this Custom Action?

Comment: Have you tried to uncheck `Is Ajax` checkbox

Comment: @MarekMusielak when i uncheck IS Ajax checkbox it give me null error

Comment: @Umang: Are you referring to getting Sitecore forms filed values inside a custom submit action?